# What's so special about the special options for Backbone.js View?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

According to [backbone.js doc](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor) for `View`:

> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached
>   directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName`
>   and `attributes`.

I understand the `el`,`id` & `className` are used for wrapping whatever's in `render()`, but

How  *special* are `model` and `collection` in a `View` object?  Are they used by View methods at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, View methods don't use this options. `model` and `collection` will just become properties of the View object.
Quotting from source:

```
// List of view options to be merged as properties.
var viewOptions = ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName'];

// Set up all inheritable **Backbone.View** properties and methods.
_.extend(View.prototype, Events, {

  ...
  // Performs the initial configuration of a View with a set of options.
  // Keys with special meaning *(model, collection, id, className)*, are
  // attached directly to the view.
  _configure: function(options) {
    if (this.options) options = _.extend({}, this.options, options);
    for (var i = 0, l = viewOptions.length; i < l; i++) {
      var attr = viewOptions[i];
      if (options[attr]) this[attr] = options[attr];
    }
    this.options = options;
  },
  ...
```

};

Comment: If that's the case, then they're really not that special other then they're the restrict list of properties allowed to be added to View?  Hmm, that's sad.  I thought there are more magic to them.

Comment: @Henry: Backbone itself doesn't do much with the view's `model` and `collection` but extensions (such as [Marionette](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette)) can take advantage of the convention of having per-model and per-collection views with consistent interfaces.